# How to get last day of month in mysql by giving month and year as input

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to get last day of the month in MySQL by providing month and year as input.

```
Similar example, To get last day of the month by date as input
    Eg: SELECT LAST_DAY(?) as lastDate

Format: 
Input month and year: '07/2015'
Output Result: day /*Eg: 30,31*/
```

I have tried with **date Format** 
`SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT('09/2015','%m/%Y')) as lastDate` but it din't work

Answer (score 6):

You just need to convert your values to a date.  Here is one way:

```
select last_day(date(concat_ws('-', year, month, 1)))
```

Comment: How to get last day by providing the month and year format as '09/2015'.
I have tried with **date Format**
`SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_FORMAT(?,'%m/%Y')) as lastDate`

Comment: You want the function `str_to_date()`, not `date_format()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
set @year:=2010;
set @month:=10;
select last_day(concat(@year,'-',@month,'-01')) as last_day;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY('2015-9-1'),'%d')

just add an any number date (day) in the query, and then get last day only using date format %d