# How can i adapt by query to get the last BUSINESS/WORKING day of each month in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

all,

trying to adapt the below query to get this for the last business day of say month may, june or whatever?

```
select distinct
month(createddate),
year(CreatedDate),
id,
value1,
vaue2,
createddate,
count( distinct id)
from 
table

and value2 IN ('harry','sally')

AND createddate > LAST_DAY( '2020-05-21') ## i need last business day here for may. 
AND createddate < '2020-06-01' ##  i need first day of next month here
group by month(createddate),
year(CreatedDate), id,value1, value2,createddate
```

ive not used mysql in a while, is there  a way i can use a function or stored procedures to find this out? if so how

*** by business day i mean working day, not a weekend***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get last day of month in mysql by giving month and year as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968328/how-to-get-last-day-of-month-in-mysql-by-giving-month-and-year-as-input)

Comment: no because i want the last business day not last day.

Comment: Please define 'last business day' of a month.

Comment: please see edits.

Comment: Define 'bank holiday'  i think they are different per country ? Do you have them stored somewhere in a table in your database?

Comment: ok lets just say  working day then not bank holiday .

Comment: With [WEEKDAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) you can get the day of the week, so you can calculate last Friday of the month.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get the First and Last weekday of a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072721/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-first-and-last-weekday-of-a-month)

Comment: @gmiley as i have put above it does not becasue i need the last business day/

Comment: @Maths12 that is what the link I posted does. It has solutions to find the last week day. If you need bank holidays, as mentioned, you will need a region specific lookup of those days to check against.

Comment: *i need the last business day* What a problem? `LAST_DAY(date) - INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(date)) WHEN 5 THEN 1 WHEN 6 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END DAY`

Comment: ok i see cheers

Comment: Also, 'working days' has a relative meaning, some people do work on saturdays or sundays...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to avoid weekend days.  So:

```
(createddate > last_day('2020-05-21') and dayofweek(last_day('2020-05-21') between 2 and 6 or
 createddate > last_day('2020-05-21') - interval 1 day and dayofweek(last_day('2020-05-21') = 7 or
 createddate > last_day('2020-05-21') - interval 2 day and dayofweek(last_day('2020-05-21') = 1
)
```